# < between two type(str) in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm learning python with the book: *"How to think like a computer scientist: Learning with python 3"* and this came out: My problem is in the last `elif` and `else`. how can we compare two string types with <.

Both the `bigger_vocab` list and `book_words` are string types and I cant understand why it uses this `<`.

Please help me and if you need more info ill try to answer even though I'm not that good when it comes to explaining.

```
def find_unknowns_merge_pattern(vocab, wds):
    #Both the vocab and wds must be sorted.  Return a new
    #list of words from wds that do not occur in vocab.

    result = []
    xi = 0
    yi = 0

    while True:
        if xi >= len(vocab):
            result.extend(wds[yi:])
            return result

        if yi >= len(wds):
            return result

        if vocab[xi] == wds[yi]:  # Good, word exists in vocab
            yi += 1

        elif vocab[xi] < wds[yi]: # Move past this vocab word,
            xi += 1

        else:                     # Got word that is not in vocab
            result.append(wds[yi])
            yi += 1

all_words = get_words_in_book("AliceInWonderland.txt")
t0 = time.clock()
all_words.sort()
book_words = remove_adjacent_dups(all_words)
missing_words = find_unknowns_merge_pattern(bigger_vocab, book_words)
t1 = time.clock()
print("There are {0} unknown words.".format(len(missing_words)))
print("That took {0:.4f} seconds.".format(t1-t0))
```

Comment: The approach here is quite odd. If you are merely checking whether one element of the list of words `vocab` exists in the list of words `wds`, then just do `if vocab[xi] in wds`. The approach is odd to me because you are looping over the indices using a `while` statement, which is bizarre. Is there a reason that you are using a `while` loop and not a `for` loop?

Comment: @rahlf23:  Comparing two sorted lists in this manner is a very efficient algorithm.  You get your result in a single pass over both lists O(n).  If he did `vocab[xi] in wds` that would be a single pass .  If he did that for each word that would be quadratic time O(n^2).  (Of course in the original algorithm you pay for the initial sorting of `vocab` and `wds`, but that's O(n log n) which is much better than quadratic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comparison operators `==,!=,>,<,>=,<=` on strings just like you can for integers or floats. The way the comparisons for strings are made are roughly in alphabetical order by comparing character ASCII values character by character. See [here](http://thepythonguru.com/python-strings/) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The question comes down to "What happens when we compare two strings?".  Basically, a string `A` is considered to be 'less than' string `B` if `A` comes before `B` alphabetically.  So `ape` is 'less than' `badger`, because  `a` comes before `b` in the alphabet.

Because both `vocab` and `wds` are sorted, this loop basically keeps track of which word in `wds` we are currently checking, and then skips words in `vocab` until either the current word in `vocab` matches the current word in `wds` (in which case the index in `vocab` moves up one word) or the current word in `wds` is 'greater' than the current word in `vocab`, in which case we move on to the next vocab word.

If the current word in `vocab` is 'badger', then you can skip forward through `wds` until the current word in `wds` is either greater than 'badger' (in which case 'badger' was not in the `wds` list), or the current word in `wds` *is* 'badger' (in which case you add 'badger' to your result list and then move on to the next vocab word to look for).

Comment: Good.  The OP should note that capitalization can screw up order.  `'ape' < 'badger'` evaluates to `True` but `'ape' < 'Badger'` evaluates to `False`.  In a real-world scenario make sure the words are all in the same case.  (The book example probably makes sure the word list is already in the same case.  Otherwise `'the'` and `'The'` would be different words and sort to different spots.)

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two string, you are checking their *alphabetical order**:

```
print('A' > 'B') # False

print('AAA' > 'AAB') # False

print('BAA' > 'AAA') # True
```

lowercase letters comes before uppercase letters:

```
print('z' > 'A') # True
```

and string of number are last:

```
print('c' > '1') # True

print('B' > '0') # True
```

---

*What we are actually checking isn't exactly the *alphabetical order*, it's instead the [ASCII value](https://www.asciitable.com/) of each character (where the letters are ordered alphabetically).
you can print the ASCII value of each char with `print(ord('A'))`:

```
print(ord('A')) # 65
print(ord('B')) # 66
print(ord('z')) # 122
print(ord('1')) # 49
print(ord('0')) # 48
```

With these premises, we do expect that *@* (`ord('@')) = 64`) is lower than *}* (`ord('}') = 125`):

```
print('@' < '}') # True
```